# Regex a string with unknown number of parameters

Tags: regex, awk, replace, sed

Let say I have millions of string in a text file in this format:

```
st=expand&c=22&t=button&k=fun HTTP
```

This is a string we can look at as a hash with keys `st`, `c`, `t` and `k`. Some of the strings in the text file might not have a given &KEY=VALUE present and might thus look like this:

```
st=expand&k=fun HTTP
```

How would one use sed to change the string to following

```
expand,,,fun
```

that is, even thought the key=value isn't present, we still add a comma. We can assume that we have a fixed key set `[st,c,t,k]`.

What I've tried is something like (just an idea!!)

```
sed 's/\(st=\|c=\|t=\|k=\)\([\(^\&\|HTTP\)])\(\&\|HTTP\)/\3,/g' big_file
```

but obviously, if `c` isn't there, it isn't adding a comma since it doesn't find any. Any ideas how to approach this? Using `awk` might also be acceptable (or any other fast text-processing utility)

Thanks!

---

### Input data example

```
st=expand&c=22&t=button&k=fun HTTP
c=22&t=button&k=fun HTTP
st=expand&c=22&t=party&k=fun HTTP
st=expand&c=22&k=fun HTTP
st=expand HTTP
 HTTP
```

### Output data

```
expand,22,button,fun
,22,button,fun
expand,22,party,fun
expand,22,,fun
expand,,,
,,,
```

Comment: No, the 3 is irrelevant there, please don't pay to much attention to the example >) 
Just put it there to show how I'm thinking this (by matching something and put `,` when there could be nothing to match)

Comment: I think it will be better to show more input data with your expected output

Comment: Why sed? It's totally the wrong tool for the job. Use a real programming language, split the string on `&` and the parts on `=` into a hashtable and output them.

Comment: I have a "file" with about 2 billion lines, really need the performance. And since I'm already using sed to change other things in that file, I was hoping I could use it with the other sed commands. Maybe that's not possible, but I guess that's the reason why I'm here.

Comment: That's going to be what, 20GB+? Aren't you going to be IO limited, not processor limited?

Comment: Good point @TessellatingHeckler . However, it's not the case here. It's coming in batches which are loaded in memory and more operations are being done in the progress so lowering the CPU load is quite essential (if possible)

Comment: Are the parameters always in the same order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(st=([^& ]*)|)(.*c=([^& ]*)|)(.*t=([^& ]*)|)(.*k=([^& ]*)|) HTTP/\2,\4,\6,\8/' file

expand,22,button,fun
,22,button,fun
expand,22,party,fun
expand,22,,fun
expand,,,
,,,
```

[Sed Demo](http://ideone.com/AuL82E)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lH0vM4/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? It's not perfectly strict, but as long as your data follows the format you described on every line, it will work.

Regex:
`^(?:st=([^&\n]*))?&?(?:c=([^&\n]*))?&?(?:t=([^&\n]*))?&?(?:k=([^&\n]*))? HTTP$` (must be run once per line or with multi-line and global options enabled)

Substitution:
`\1,\2,\3,\4`

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/nE1oP7/2

EDIT: If you are using sed, you will need to change the non-capturing groups to regular ones (`(?:)` to `()`) and update the backreferences accordingly (`\2,\4,\6,\8`). Demo: http://ideone.com/GNRNGp

Comment: If you're going to post a regexp then please show it working in the context of a specific tool. Showing it working in some online "regex validator" tool is useless unless you're proposing the OP uploads his input files to that web site to run the regexp on them. The regexp you posted will not work in any standard UNIX tool.

Comment: How is it useless? The point of playground tools is to let you experiment on small sets of data so you can see what's going on. I provided a suggestion for the logic. It may require some tweaking, but an answer does not have to be in the context of a specific tool to be valuable.

Comment: It is useless because it will not work in any of the tools the OP is using and it will not require tweaking to work, it will require a complete rewrite. You may as well tell the OP how to do it in assembly code for all the practical good it'll do him. To be accurate you would have to change your EDIT to say `This will not work in sed, awk or any other standard UNIX tool. You will have to completely rewrite the syntax depending on the tool you end up using.`. If it'd work in perl or ruby or something (which I doubt but idk) then at least give readers a clue about which, if any, WOULD work.

Comment: You're being a bit rude about this. Remember, answers are not just helpful to the person asking the question, but also to other people who come across the question later with a similar situation who may have a different environment, but the same business problem. Again, I provided a suggestion. It will absolutely work in some regex parsers. I was not aware that it won't work in sed when I wrote it, but it still helps the OP think about how to construct such a pattern.

Comment: I went ahead and got it working with sed with the very minor tweak of changing the non-capturing groups to regular ones and updating the backreferences. Exactly as I said, it simply required a little adjustment to suit the tool and not a complete rewrite as you stated. Demo: http://ideone.com/GNRNGp There was no need to tear down my answer the way you did, and you are absolutely incorrect that my answer is useless as written, as I have shown here. Whether you meant it or not, your comments carry an ego that detracts from the collaborative environment here.

Comment: Note that I also removed the usages of `\n` for the sed example since they are not necessary when comparing line by line, although it works fine with them in there.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have name=value pairs in your input data, it's simplest and clearest and usually most efficient to create a name->value array and then print the values by name in whatever order you want, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[&= ]"; OFS="," }
{
    delete n
    for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) {
        n[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
    print n["st"], n["c"], n["t"], n["k"]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
expand,22,button,fun
,22,button,fun
expand,22,party,fun
expand,22,,fun
expand,,,
,,,
```

Answer (score 1):

Another pattern for `sed` to try:

```
sed -r "s/(st=(\w+))?(&?c=(\w+))?(&t=(\w+))?(&k=(\w+))?( HTTP)/\2,\4,\6,\8/g" big_file

expand,22,button,fun
,22,button,fun
expand,22,party,fun
expand,22,,fun
expand,,,
```

[REGEX 101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jE7vJ1/1)